# Emacs creates autosave file named ##

Tags: emacs, autosave, backups

I have configured Emacs to send autosaves to the /tmp directory:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

However, when editing the file Foo, instead of creating #Foo#, it creates ## - just two hashes. This then causes the warning "Bar has autosave data" every time I open a new file, since the /tmp/## file apparently pattern-matches every possible filename. I assume I'm setting the auto-save-file-name-transforms variable wrong; what should I set it to to create /tmp/#Foo# autosaves? (Or alternatively, what else do I need to change?)

Possibly relevant information:

- Emacs 21.4.1
- RHEL 5.3 (Tikanga)
- Most of my files are version-controlled by git
- vc-make-backup-files is nil (but setting it to t doesn't change the behaviour)

Comment: My configuration is similar to yours and it works just fine. I do notice that your Emacs is positively *ancient*. Version 21.4.1 isn't even hosted on [the GNU FTP site](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/) anymore, but it looks like 21.4 came out in 2005. (This is probably because your *OS* is ancient; [RHEL 5.3 was released in 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#RHEL_5). At least upgrade to 5.10!) Any chance you could upgrade Emacs to version 24, or at least version 23?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the environment on this box. :(

Comment: Actually, I don't touch `auto-save-file-name-transforms`. I am using its default setting, which on Emacs 24.3 is `(("\\`/[^/]*:\\([^/]*/\\)*\\([^/]*\\)\\'" "/tmp/\\2" t))`. Is there a reason you're changing it? My guess is that's the problem.

Comment: Because that's the recipe I found online; I read it on the 'net so it must be true... Anyway, commenting out that line makes the autosave files have sensible #Foo# names. They don't get put in the /tmp directory, but I can live with that; unlike backups they don't clutter things up forever. Thanks!

Comment: If you do `C-h v temporary-file-directory`, does it show `/tmp`?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it does.

Comment: I use `"."` instead of `".*"` in `backup-directory-alist` and also do not touch `auto-save-file-name-transforms`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this [See second section by Amit Patel](https://snarfed.org/gnu_emacs_backup_files)